# How to pass a variable to fabric run()

Tags: fabric

I am using fabric run() method to do some remote tasks, I read the documentation but doesn't seem I can insert a variable to run() to do something more meaningful for e.g.

REMOTE_HOME=/var/somedir

remote_dirlist=[a,b,c,d,e]

These dirs are present on remote system, I want to loop over the this generated list and use run("rm -fr") to remove these dirs. What is the best way to do achieve this? I tried looking with "cd" (context_manager) but that won't work in this case it seems.

Comment: I am not sure if I do understand your question, but why don't you do `run("rm -fr %s" % dir_to_remove) ` ?

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. May be I read the documentation too fast.